# Ionic apply multiple filters to a list

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I receive data something like following, which I am populating in a list:

```
 tasks =   [
        {
            title: "One",
            prop1: "Lorem",
            prop2: "Lorem",
            prop3: "Lorem"
        },
        {
            title: "Two",
            prop1: "Lorem",
            prop2: "Lorem",
            prop3: "Lorem"
        },
        ...
    ]
```

and the list template

```
  <ion-list>
    <button detail-none (click)="expandItem(task)" ion-item *ngFor="let task of tasks">
      <h2>{{task.title}}</h2>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
```

I want to filter this list according to multiple filters applied as per prop1, prop2, prop3 etc.

For which I have select boxes:

```
  <ion-row padding>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Frequence of performance</ion-label>
          <ion-select>
            <ion-option *ngFor="let frequency of prop1_options" value="{{frequency.value}}">{{frequency.title}}</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Importance</ion-label>
          <ion-select>
            <ion-option *ngFor="let importance of prop2_options" value="{{importance.value}}">{{importance.title}}</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Importance of improvement</ion-label>
          <ion-select>
            <ion-option *ngFor="let improvement of filer_per_improvement" value="{{improvement.value}}">{{improvement.title}}</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Stakeholder</ion-label>
          <ion-select>
            <ion-option *ngFor="let stakeholder of prop3_options" value="{{stakeholder.value}}">{{stakeholder.title}}</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

My understanding is I will need to create pipes to achieve this, but I am not sure how should I create those? Just one pipe or multiple, and what about performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this article help you code your pipe? https://amitthakkar.github.io/Pipes-In-Angular2/

From the page I linked it shows how to declare a pipe :

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({name: 'range'})
    export class RangePipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(minValue:number, maxValue:number):number[] {
            let range = [];
            for (let index = minValue; index <= maxValue; index++) {
                range.push(index);
            }
            return range;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I am more curious to figure out if I need to write one pipe that should handle all the filtering with different parameters or rather multiple pipes? Because as I was reading, applying many filters slows the performance of the app

Comment: that's up to personal choice on what you gauge is best for the matter. If I were doing it, I would opt for a combined filter, in favor of performance and in detriment to code readability. you have to pick your poison. and I would personally put it in in a single filter call : `this.yourFilteredResult = this.yourArrayName.filter( x => { return (eval criterea A && eval critera B && eval criterea C && eval critera D)});` (filter() is a native method you can string on an array)

Comment: @Nitish did this solve your issue? care to mark me as answer? thanks :)